# Sign MSIX Bundle with .crt certificate

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, code-signing, code-signing-certificate, msix

I've built a WPF application using Visual Studio 2019.
I'm using a Windows Application Packaging Project to create the MSIX Bundle.
I had been signing it with a self signed certificate (only good for debugging) and it works fine.

I recently purchased an EV Code Signing certificate from SSL.com (it's a .crt file) and can't seem use it to sign the application. It comes in a YubiKey or you can download the file.

The problem is that if I try to select a certificate using the "Select from file" option it only lets me pick .pfx certificates.

If I try to select a certificate using the "Select from store" option my certificate doesn't show up. (The only ones I see are the ones that I created while debugging).
If I view the certificate store using Microsoft Management Console I can see the certificate in there but for some reason VS doesn't recognise it.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: You need the private key that's included in the `.pfx` file to be able to sign the package.

Comment: Thanks @mm8 the company that I bought the certificate from are telling me that they don't have access to the private key. Do you know what are the best places to get a certificate for Visual Studio & msix bundles?

Comment: Either buy from a trusted authority or [create one yourself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/create-certificate-package-signing).